# unable to display high resolution pictures inside ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I am making an application where i want to display gallery of high resolution pictures For.eg(1920 X 1200). When I set the  `items.add(new Item("Red",       R.drawable.wall1));` with this high resolution pictures it crashes. How can this be achieved.
Please help me experts. Thanks in advance.

```
 public class ImageGalleryActivity extends Activity {
    String strCategoryName = null;
    GridView gridView;
    Utils utils;
    private int columnWidth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        Intent intent;
        intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            strCategoryName = intent.getStringExtra("category");
        }



        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_cards);
            gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("Red",       R.drawable.wall1));
        items.add(new Item("Magenta",   R.drawable.img10));
        items.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.img11));
        items.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.img12));
        items.add(new Item("Green",     R.drawable.img13));
        items.add(new Item("Cyan",      R.drawable.img14));
        items.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.img11));
        items.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.img12));
        items.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.img11));
        items.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.img12));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if(v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout_square_image_view, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

    private class Item {
        final String name;
        final int drawableId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.drawableId = drawableId;
        }
    }
}
```

Log cat Error.

```
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:349)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at com.example.paperfreepost.MyAdapter.getView(ImageGalleryActivity.java:155)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-12 08:19:59.004: E/AndroidRuntime(16159):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log from the logcat?

Comment: use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader for displaying image.

Comment: @Sripathi: Please find the log in the editted post

Comment: from where you are displaying images

Comment: @BirajZalavadia: Getting the images from Drawable folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this method**

```
public Bitmap decodeImage(int resourceId) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100; // you are free to modify size as your requirement

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

**Call it from adapter**

```
picture.setImageBitmap((decodeImage(item.drawableId));
```

instead this line

```
 picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
```

Comment: I have tried your code it works. But is it more efficient then the code provided by @yushulx for the same post. I am able to get my problem for both of your code. But now i want efficiency because ill be loading many pictures at a time.

Comment: Also at click event of the the thumbnail I want to display this image on full screen how can this be done.

Comment: the above method is prepared for general purpose i.e If you want to change the size of you image you can easily change the respective parameters will set accordingly set. You can change REQUIRED_SIZE variable as your need ,

Comment: How can i send the selected Image to other activity. I want to set the selected Image as backgorund image for the other activity layout.

Comment: do not send the entire image just send the resource id in intent

Comment: How will i get the resource id ?

Comment: the way you are using in adapter

Comment: The gird view works perfectly fine but the scrolling is laggy and takes time not smooth. I checked with Picasso and ImageLoader, but ImageLoader I dint come to know how to use it. Picasso I used but it dint solve my problem. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52570/discussion-between-mayur-and-biraj-zalavadia)

Comment: I have implemented the edited code. I worked smooth, but while scrolling I have noticed that the small thumbnail displayed with wrong image for little while and then the real image is displayed.

Comment: Don't worry It is expected behavior. It also happens with me

Comment: The activity crashes after almost 4 to 5 times different pictures are loaded and this activity is called. Also noticed when the orientation was changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your image size. The better way is to decode the image to a bitmap, and set the bitmap to the ImageView. For example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 4;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), item.drawableId, opts);
picture.setImageBitmap (bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying a gallery? multiple images in a grid?

You may want to display thumbnails in the grid, and ontouch display the high resolution image. There is no way to render multiple high resolution images all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_cards);
        Intent intent;
        intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            strCategoryName = intent.getStringExtra("category");
        }



        List<Item> items =  new List<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("Red",       R.drawable.wall1));
        items.add(new Item("Magenta",   R.drawable.img10));
        items.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.img11));
        items.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.img12));
        items.add(new Item("Green",     R.drawable.img13));
        items.add(new Item("Cyan",      R.drawable.img14));
        items.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.img11));
        items.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.img12));
        items.add(new Item("Dark Gray", R.drawable.img11));
        items.add(new Item("Gray",      R.drawable.img12));
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,items));
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private List<Item> items;
        private Context context;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.frame_layout_square_image_view, null, false);
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.picture.setImageResource(items.get(position).drawableId);
            holder.text.setText(items.get(position).name);

            return convertView;
        }


        class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView picture;

        }
    }
```